# Get relative URL for a Microsoft article

Tags: sharepoint-online, iframe

I am very clueless when it comes to developing, so my question may seem dumb, but here goes nothing. I will present you the scenario I am trying to work with:

- in SharePoint Online, on the modern interface, we have created pages where we added the embeded code webpart and added a link to a microsoft article in an iFrame like so:

`<iframe src="https://support.office.com/en-us/article/upload-a-folder-or-files-to-a-document-library-eb18fcba-c953-4d45-8d90-8da66edeacdb"width="1600" height="1000"</iframe>`

- Since the users are based in multiple locations around the world, we need to make the content in this webpart available in the browser language of the current user.

My question is: how to modify the absolute URL and turn it into a relative URL in the iframe so that the user sees the content in his browser language (set by GPO based on location from I know)

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Regards,

Alexandra Prisacaru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the URL and remove the "en-us/". When the user visits the link, they should be redirected to the correct language version... if there is one.

```
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/upload-a-folder-or-files-to-a-document-library-eb18fcba-c953-4d45-8d90-8da66edeacdb
```

With edit:

```
https://support.office.com/article/upload-a-folder-or-files-to-a-document-library-eb18fcba-c953-4d45-8d90-8da66edeacdb
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike! I tested and it worked! You are a life savior.